How to combine Android Studio and Jmeter with different versions of JAVA?
In my work I should use both Android Studio Iguana (which requires Java 21) and Apache Jmeter (which requires Java 8). When I used previous version Android Studio with earlier versions of Java (8, 11) my Jmeter works normally, but when I update to Java 21 Jmeter stop working, it doesnt even start (after doubleclick on ApacheJMeter.jar nothing happens). I have Macbook pro, 13.5 Ventura and
I try to install Java 8 on my Mac in addition to Java 21 and use command export JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8 (in Terminal's tab on directory "bin" ) but it shows me export: not valid in this context: -v.
But after running /usr/libexec/java_home -V I see:
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
21.0.2 (x86_64) "Amazon.com Inc." - "Amazon Corretto 21" /Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-21.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_412 (x86_64) "Amazon" - "Amazon Corretto 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home
/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-21.jdk/Contents/Home

Apache JMeter 5.6 needs minimum Java 8, it means that you won't be able to run it using previous versions of Java.
It's not a problem to run JMeter on Java 21 (you can face some problems with JSR223 Sampler though)

And it's also not a problem to amend jmeter.sh startup script and point it to whatever Java version you want, i.e. if you add the next line as the first one:
PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/amazon-corretto-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH

then JMeter will be launched using Java 8

sorry, I forgot to specify version of Jmeter - 5.0 (I try later versions of it but there are problems with libs and plugins which used with my JMX-script).
Anyway, I tried to to amend jmeter.sh startup script like this (below I show part of code in jmeter.sh to show how file looks now):
**...
N.B. readlink would be a lot simpler but is not supported on Solaris.
PATH=/Users/username/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-1.8.0_412/Contents/Home/bin:$PATH.
PRG="$0".
while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
...**
But nothing works. Where I go wrong?
